# What are the uses of ellipses in essays?

Tags: grammar, writing, ellipses

I’m wondering about how ellipses are used in essays. Are there any examples that I could see?

Comment: This question seems incredibly vague, could you try to be a bit more specific about what you're asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of ellipsis (examples from *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage*):

1. Ellipsis in the grammar of a sentence

   > They took glasses from the bar and [they took] plates from the tables.
2. Ellipsis in punctuation

   > He wanted no more of it . . . But having said that . . .

Answer (score 5):

When I quote a long passage I might elide some irrelevant parts, and in their place I put ellipses.

For example,

> When I quote a long passage, like when I quote from an old email or when I quote from a taxation bill to illustrate a nuanced legal point, I might elide some irrelevant parts, and in their place I put ellipses.

becomes

> When I quote a long passage ... I might elide some irrelevant parts, and in their place I put ellipses.

Comment: Or some relevant parts, if removing them supports my argument. :-)

Comment: @Chris Goes without saying ;-)

Comment: @Ed Guiness: Excellent example, but I think you have placed the ellipses in the wrong place. Shouldn't they go between "passage" and "I might", since that is where you have removed words from the original quote?

Comment: I was taught to bracket the ellipses in this case. For example: "Shouldn't they go […] where you have removed words from the original quote?"