# Proper way to quote the end of a saying (ellipsis use and capitalization)

Tags: capitalization, quotations, ellipses

The quote goes:

> So next time someones complains that you have made a mistake, tell them that may be a good thing, because without imperfection, neither you nor I would exist.

I only want the last part:

> Without imperfection neither you nor I would exist.

Would I write it like so, or use an ellipsis at the start:

> . . . Without imperfection, neither you nor I would exist.

I guess that if I used an ellipsis, it wouldn’t have a capital letter on *without*, would it?

Comment: I don't know where "the quote" comes from in this case, but why bother with the ellipsis for a bit you don't want? We don't do it before or after every snippet of Shakespeare we "quote".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Haven’t you noticed . . . that people . . . today . . . tend to use . . . ***ｅｌｌｉｐｓｅｓ*** . . . all over the . . . fricking place . . . with wanton abandon . . . ?

Comment: @tchrist: I am intrigued by what elided words all your ellipses represent, to reduce to such a wonderful whole sentence

Comment: Is that quote from Thomas Watson Jr. by any chance? (http://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/800603.Thomas_J_Watson_Jr_ and http://thinkexist.com/quotes/thomas_j._watson/)

Comment: @Pieter: [Stephen Hawking](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/363982-one-of-the-basic-rules-of-the-universe-is-that), apparently. [Into The Universe with Stephen Hawking (2010) *So next time someone complains that you have made a mistake, tell him that may be a good thing. Because without imperfection, neither you nor I would exist.*](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Stephen_Hawking)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/81495/44619

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the uses of ellipses in essays?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/what-are-the-uses-of-ellipses-in-essays)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of an ellipsis, you can use [square brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Square_brackets) to indicate light editing in a quotation. They are often used to add minor clarifications or make the quoted text better fit the context, and they're specifically used for the case you're asking about:

> Additionally, a small letter can be replaced by a capital one, when the beginning of the original text is omitted for succinctness, for example, when referring to a verbose original.

For example: “[W]ithout imperfection, neither you nor I would exist.”

Answer (score 0):

For me: "... without imperfection, neither you nor I would exist."

Comment: Please explain why. In my view, it would depend on context. Following OP's question, your suggestion would be incorrect at the beginning of a sentence because there would be no capital letter. In mid-sentence, if the quotation begins with a small letter it is obviously mid-sentence in the original and so an ellipsis is superfluous. In many cases an ellipsis is necessary only when words are omitted *in the middle* of a quotation.